# Trying to pull files into my local branch from a remote repo, but not all files seem to be getting pulled

Tags: git, github

I created a remote from the local repo I want to pull from. I then fetch it, and made a branch from it with `git checkout -b test *remote-name*/*remote-branch*` so I now have it as a branch that I'm in.

But for whatever reason, it's missing some script files it has on the github page. What did I do wrong?

Now that I'm in that branch I then did `git pull *remote-name* *remote-branch*` and it still doesn't have the files I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to switch branches from master to your remote branch?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the branch I create with that first checkout statement.

Comment: I'd suggest simply cloning your github directory into a clean slate directory and then checking out and pulling the new branch. Brute force but it helps sometimes when things get murky :)